# Why is cin changing the address of my reference variable?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and created some experimental cases for myself to learn about references and pointers. I ran into a situation where I would pass in a reference variable to a function, but when I tried to change its value within the function, the value change did not persist outside of the function. It took me a long time to narrow down what was happening, and it turns out that the function `cin.ignore()` was changing the address of my variable.

Test code:

```
int main() {
    bool mainBool = false;
    printf("Address of mainBool: %p\n", &mainBool);
    while (!mainBool) {
        boolTest(mainBool);
    }
    return 0;
}

void boolTest(bool & var) {
    printf("Address of bool passed in: %p\n", &var);
    printf("> ");
    char input[2];
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cin.ignore();
    printf("Address of bool after cin.ignore(): %p\n", &var);
    var = true;
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of mainBool: 0x7ffeefbff4bb
Address of bool passed in: 0x7ffeefbff4bb
> 00
Address of bool after cin.ignore(): 0x7ffeefbff400
Address of bool passed in: 0x7ffeefbff4bb
>
```

With "00" as my user input, the main() function loops forever.

I recognize that my usage of `cin.ignore()` in this case is not properly set up to accommodate an incorrect length of input. But I don't understand why this is changing the address of my variable within this scope. Can anyone explain or point me to some resources that might explain what is happening under the hood?

Comment: Please, note that [istream operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) is not aware of arrays until C++20. I strongly guess you have Undefined Behavior. The `std::cin >> input;` reads and stores more than 2 characters. (It adds a 0-terminator which results in 3 characters.) This might be the reason why it corrupts your `bool &var`.

Comment: Try moving your `printf` statement to after the `cin >> input`.  Note that you don't tell `cin` *how many characters to read*.  When you type in "00\n", the `cin` will fill your character array as follows: `input[0] = '0', input[1] = '0'; input[2] = 0x00;` which may overwrite variables.

Comment: More accurately, @ThomasMatthews, it _will_ overwrite the _stack_ where the compiler may have stashed a value - not a user-declared variable.  For example, in this case, it may have stashed the address of the parameter `var` there for some reason - to use it in both printf calls, perhaps (because, being cdecl, the _caller_ cleans up arguments)?

Comment: One of the coolest things about programming is where you spot the bug is rarely where the bug actually occurred. Doesn't sound cool to you? It should. It's one of the things that keeps us all employed and earning decent wages.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that you've run into a buffer overflow and therefore undefined behaviour. The trouble is that `char input[2];` can hold only two characters and no more. Unfortunately, your input of `"00"` requires *three* characters to store as a C string - you can't forget the null terminator!

Comment: *you can't forget the null terminator!* Wish this was literally true. Save a lot of bugs.

Comment: I just learned about this too!! I was trying to keep it in mind, but I got muddled because I don't have to explicitly accommodate the null terminator when declaring like `char string[] = "Hello"`. But of course it's different for input.

Comment: Given that this is a C++ question, I feel obligated to point out that abstractions like `::std::string` and others are very useful in these situations! Of course, experimenting with fundamentals is still valuable, provided you're aware that safer and easier options exist and should generally be used in the real world.

Comment: I tend to agree - however, the vast majority of tutorials and beginner's courses out there start out teaching newbies about char arrays before teaching them about strings. I certainly don't prefer having to learn and then unlearn habits, but that seems to be the state of C++ instruction right now.